# phpOffice is not converting .docx file to pdf. it shows error DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, doc, phpoffice

hello guys i am working in laravel 5 and trying to convert my .docx files to pdf files. If there is only text in .docx file it converts successfully. But if there is any image in .docx file it shows following error

```
DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix
```

i am using phpOffice.
I simply, loaded word file

```
$Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($sourceDoc);
```

and tried to save it into pdf

```
$PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
```

anybody can please help me. thanks.